# Azure logic app allows only one language for captions translations. How to extend logic app to custom web page?

Tags: html, forms, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-cognitive-services

I have built an Azure logic app, that will output an VTT transcript file, once a video has been uploaded. Link to the API: https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Get-Video-Index.  However, I am trying to find a way to let a user choose outside of the logic app, what language they want the captions to be translated in.

How can I build a simple web app/page that will allow a user to choose a language from a radio button with a list of languages and then loop that back to a logic app?
For example I want to build something like this and then wire it up to my logic app "Caption Language" field:

How can I create a HTML form and loop that inside my Azure Logic app? What is the efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things:

1. How will the user select the item
2. How you will use it as a parameter in your logic App

For the 1st point, it's totally up to you: choose the technology you prefer, and go. The thing that you have to understand is how it is linked to the 2nd point.

What you could do for this 2nd point:

- Add a custom payload to your Logic App HTTP Trigger content: you can define it by using a sample:

[image: Payload]

That will create the following schema:
[image: Payload schema]

- Use this chosen language as an input in your Logic App query, and set this parameter in the field "Captions language", using "Enter custom value":

[image: Captions lang]

You must point to the value in your payload:

[image: setup lang]

So when you call your logic app from your web page, ensure that when you submit your form, your make a POST to your logic app url and pass in the body a content which is

```
{ "lang": "yourSelectedLanguageCode" }
```

Comment: I am stuck on this step "Use this chosen language as an input in your Logic App query, and set this parameter in the field "Captions language", using "Enter custom value" How can I set the language as an input in the logic app query?

Comment: Did you see the captures? And processed all the steps?

Comment: can you show how to pass in chosen language as a input in my logic app?

Comment: It's my last capture in my answer!

Comment: @Nicocals I will have look at it and get back to you. I am still working on building the User Interface. Thank you  !

Comment: one question, what if I want to choose more than one language at a time? is that possible(create a checkbox) ? This way, we can reduce the indexing efforts, every time we select a language.

Comment: what if instead of a dropdown option, I create a check box where a user can select multiple languages at a time for translation. Will I be able to pass in multiple languages at a time as an input parameter to my logic app?

Comment: you can use an array of langs instead a single param yes. and you have to create a loop based on this array length on your logic app on the step where you get the index

Comment: can you please give an example of what you meant by “array of lang” I seem to be very confused. Any example can help. Thanks.

Comment: if you can show example with your screen shot capture, it will help me understand better. I just don't understand this part  **"you can use an array of langs instead a single param yes. and you have to create a loop based on this array length on your logic app on the step where you get the index "**

Comment: please use one question at a time. Here the question was "how to get a caption in a specific language?". You should not start discussing additional things on a reply, as it is misleading for other people looking for similar things, thanks

Comment: You posted 3 or 4 questions around the same thing... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
 I'm stopping here, sorry

Comment: Hi Nicolas please have look at this question this different, I can assure you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336934/how-to-create-an-azure-logic-app-that-allows-multiple-languages-selection-for-t  . I created an custom web page that allows a user to choose more than one language, and I was able to send that data to the logic app but I am not sure how to create the custom caption field. (It is similar to what you have show here in this question, expect in my new question, the user can select multiple languages. How will the workflow of the logic app look now?

Comment: You should clean all your questions first, creating one more question on this topic will not help